# Django 1.8 admin - saving existing model with existing inlines breaks

Tags: django, django-admin, django-1.7, django-1.8

In all my admin change forms that contain inlined related models, trying to save the existing models throws errors related to duplicate in the related inlines. Either because of queries returning many instances, or uniqueness validation failures

Switching from Django 1.7 to 1.8 with produces this behavior. Switching back to 1.7 with same code base fixes the issue.

Anyone seen this? Any idea where to debug?

Comment: give your models.py and admin.py

Comment: I'll try reducing this into a minimal example